# Нумерованый список и под список

Tags: html, css, ul

Есть нумерованный список который начинается с "1". Нужно сделать так чтобы под список начинался с цифры- с которой начинается родительский элемент.

[image: Список и под список]
Возможно ли сделать такое средствами css без js?

```css
.list {
    color: $color-primary;
    font-weight: 600;

    & > li {
        &:before {
            margin-right: 1.2rem;
        }

        ul {
            color: $color-minor-dark;

            li {
                &:before {
                    margin-right: 1.2rem;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &.numeration {
        counter-reset: list decimal;

        & > li {
            list-style-type: none;

            &:before {
                counter-increment: list;
                content: counter(list) ".";
                color: $color-active;
            }

            ul {
                counter-reset: list decimal;

                & > li {
                    &:before {
                        counter-increment: lists;
                        content: counter(lists) "." counter(decimal);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &.sm {
        font-size: 1.4rem;

        & > li {
            & + li {
                margin-top: 1.2rem;
            }

            ul {
                margin-top: 1.2rem;
                margin-left: 1.6rem;

                & > li {
                    margin-top: 1.2rem;
                    padding-left: 1.2rem;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &.md {
        font-size: 1.6rem;

        & > li {
            & + li {
                margin-top: 1.4rem;
            }

            ul {
                margin-top: 1.4rem;
                margin-left: 1.6rem;

                & > li {
                    margin-top: 1.4rem;
                    padding-left: 1.2rem;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list numeration md">
  <li>work status</li>
  <li>annual income</li>
  <li>net worth
      <ul>
          <li>forex market</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>position 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Пробовали вместо `ul` использовать `ol`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
ol {
  /* убираем стандартную нумерацию */
  list-style: none; 
  /* Идентифицируем счетчик и даем ему имя li. Значение счетчика не указано – по умолчанию оно равно 0 */ 
  counter-reset: li; 
}

li:before {
  /* Определяем элемент, который будет нумероваться — li. Псевдоэлемент before указывает, что содержимое, вставляемое при помощи свойства content, будет располагаться перед пунктами списка. Здесь же устанавливается значение приращения счетчика (по умолчанию равно 1). */
  counter-increment: li; 
  /* С помощью свойства content выводится номер пункта списка. counters() означает, что генерируемый текст представляет собой значения всех счетчиков с таким именем. Точка в кавычках добавляет разделяющую точку между цифрами, а точка с пробелом добавляется перед содержимым каждого пункта списка */
  content: counters(li,".") ". "; 
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>пункт</li> <!-1.->
  <li>пункт           
    <ol>
      <li>пункт</li> <!-2.1.->
      <li>пункт</li> <!-2.2.->
      <li>пункт
        <ol>
          <li>пункт</li> <!-2.3.1.->
          <li>пункт</li> <!-2.3.2.->
          <li>пункт</li> <!-2.3.3.-> 
        </ol>
      </li> <!-2.3.->
      <li>пункт</li> <!-2.4.->  
    </ol>
  </li> <!-2.->
  <li>пункт</li> <!-3.->        
  <li>пункт</li> <!-4.->        
</ol>
```